# Javascript: найти на странице черный текст на черном фоне

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как с помощью Javascript найти на странице все элементы, в которых текст написан черным цветом по черному фону? При этом черный фон/цвет может быть прописан не у самого элемента, а у далекого родителя, но после всех наследований в результате получается черный по черному.

Поставили задачу: сделать на сайте версию для слабовидящих. Один из пунктов - инверсия цвета, то есть выводим белый текст на черном фоне. Я прописал черный `background` у `body`, поправил css для прочих контейнеров, все хорошо, за исключением одного но. В админке у некоторых страниц в редакторе WYSIWYG явно прописан черный цвет для текста (в атрибуте `style`). В результате этот текст не виден на странице.

Я хочу найти решение, которое позволит решить проблему, **не изменяя код страниц**.

Например, чтобы javascript автоматически находил такой текст и менял его цвет на белый. Вопрос в том, как найти такие элементы.

Пока я вижу только вариант рекурсивного прохода по всем элементам DOM с запоминанием `background` родителя и проверкой цвета самого элемента.

Но может, есть способ проще, какое-нибудь решение в пару строк на jquery?

Иными словами, нужно добиться, чтобы в примере во втором `div > p` текст был виден:

```css
.orig {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.invert {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div class="orig"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div class="invert"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>
```

Comment: Это можно сделать в очень ограниченном виде. Если элементы абсолютно позиционированы - будут проблемы. Также не получится учесть картинки (ну или эта задача будет довольно сложной)

Comment: Может быть, обрабатывать только элементе, которые создаёт WYSIWYG. Вы знаете селектор родителя этого контейнера, остается пройтись или "насильно" через !important менять цвет у потомков.

Comment: @tutankhamun эти ограничения приемлемы. Я могу ограничить поиск только контейнерами, где нет абсолютного позиционирования и картинок в `background`, собственно, основной контент страницы удовлетворяет этим требованиям.

Comment: @blatube.com цвет текста прописан через `style`, разве можно его поменять через `!important`? Насколько я знаю, что прописано в `style`, то уже не поменяешь css'ом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Пришла в голову мысль, что стили, заданные в редакторе, совсем не обязательно будут задавать тексту черный цвет — это может быть и темно-серый и какой-нибудь коричневый. Текст такого цвета на инвертированном фоне слабовидящим людям будет по-прежнему тяжело прочесть, потому надо определять контрастность текста и фона.

Код частично скопипастил с [определителя контрастности](http://leaverou.github.com/contrast-ratio) Лии Веру.

Что происходит в этом коде: функция `getLuminance()` возвращает *relative luminance*; функция `getContrastRatio()` возвращает *contrast ratio* из введенных туда данных о цвете фона и текста. Проходим по каждому параграфу внутри блока `.invert`, определяем *contrast ratio* и если он меньше 7 (таково требование WCAG) — делаем текст белым, а если больше 7, то оставляем как есть.

**UPD**: переписал код для определения цвета фона не у родителя, а у самого элемента, для этого надо прописать параграфу в CSS `background-color: inherit` и переменной `bg` присваивать значение собственного цвета фона: `bg = $(item).css('background-color')`.

**UPD**: [итоговый вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/Cronfy/r8optv2a/3/), позволяющий делать что угодно с элементами, имеющими недостаточную контрастность и без использования `background-color: inherit`.

Источники:

> [Lea Verou, contrast ratio](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/).
>
> Формула подсчёта *relative luminance*: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef.
>
> Формула подсчета *contrast ratio*: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef.

```js
$(function() {
  var color, bg, textLuminance, parentLuminance, cr;

  $('.invert p').each(function(index, item) {
    color = $(item).css('color'),
    bg = $(item).css('background-color');

    textLuminance = getLuminance(color);
    parentLuminance = getLuminance(bg);
    
    cr = getContrastRatio(textLuminance, parentLuminance);
    
    if(cr <= 7) $(item).css('color', '#fff');
  });

  function getContrastRatio(l1, l2) {
    l1 += .05,
    l2 += .05;
    
    var ratio = l1 / l2;

    if (l2 > l1) {
      ratio = 1 / ratio;
    }

    return ratio = Math.round(ratio, 1);
  }

  function getLuminance(color) {
    var rgb = color.slice(4, -1).split(',').map(Number);

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var rgbI = rgb[i];

      rgbI /= 255;

      rgbI = rgbI < .03928 ? rgbI / 12.92 : Math.pow((rgbI + .055) / 1.055, 2.4);

      rgb[i] = rgbI;
    }

    return .2126 * rgb[0] + .7152 * rgb[1] + 0.0722 * rgb[2];
  }
});
```

```css
.orig {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.invert {
  background-color: #000;
}

.invert p {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div class="orig">
  <p style="color: black">Текст</p>
</div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div class="invert">
  <p>Обычный текст без инлайновых стилей</p>
</div>

<div class="invert">
  <div style="background-color: #fff">
  <div style="background-color: #ff0">
  <div>
  <p style="color: black">Черный Текст</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="invert">
  <p style="color: brown; background: darkgrey">Коричневый Текст</p>
</div>

<div class="invert">
  <p style="color: blue">Синий Текст</p>
</div>

<div class="invert">
  <p style="color: yellow">Желтый Текст</p>
</div>

<div class="invert">
  <p style="color: orange">Оранжевый Текст</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот это просто отлично! Здорово! Осталось научиться определять реальный backgound-color элемента, потому что он может быть задан у предка. Но, видимо, придется-таки писать для этого рекурсивную функцию, так как насколько я понял, более простого способа определить реальный фон не существует.

Comment: см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: `inherit` `background-color` для `p` нельзя использовать, это приведет к неприятным сайд-эффектам, когда у какого-то предка `background` - картинка, а не просто цвет. https://jsfiddle.net/38ve0gdv/  Хотя для конкретно моего случая вариант подойдет, в контенте нет контейнеров с картинками в фоне. Но для общего случая, думаю, можно взять ф-ю отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663840/1775065 , только отсекать варианты, когда у ближайшего предка с непрозрачным фоном в качестве фона используется картинка.

Comment: `background-color: inherit` наследует *цвет фона* родителя, потому естественно, что если он задан вместе с картинкой, как в вашем примере, то этот цвет будет унаследован. Приведенная вами в качестве примера функция не делает чего-либо особенного, `.css('background-color')` вот делает то же самое. Ну и что касается отсечения фона-картинки, тут вы по-простому уже точно не сделаете, лично мне не сильно хочется писать еще и функцию для определения среднего цвета картинки — тут вы уже пытаетесь обработать все случаи со сферическим конём в вакууме ) А как это нагрузит клиент даже не хочу думать.

Comment: Верно, работа с фоном-картинкой определенно выходит за рамки задачи. Такие случаи придется просто отсекать. А вот приведенная ф-я отличается от простого `css("background-color")`, смотрите: https://jsfiddle.net/r4bpvqxh/2/ (я намеренно сделал без `Inherit`, потому что, как писал выше, к него есть ненужные сайд-эффекты).

Comment: Про `$.css("background-color")` я писал, разумеется, в связке с `background-color: inherit`, но приведенная вами функция фактически повторяет эту функциональность — вот смотрите, есть бэк с картинкой и цветом, эта функция возвращает цвет из свойства `background` https://jsfiddle.net/r4bpvqxh/3/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55528/discussion-between-sasha-omelchenko-and-cronfy).

Comment: Я немного адаптировал ваше решение, чтобы не требовался `background-color: inherit`, посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/Cronfy/r8optv2a/3/

Comment: Ну вроде норм работает )

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание на то, что функция `getLuminance()` работает только с форматом `rgb`, обработку `rgba` я выпилил, но, если понадобится, исходный код можете взять по ссылке на гитхаб Лии Веру.

Answer (score 7):

Может быть так:

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  var
    $this = $(this),
    wrap = $this.parent('div'),
    color = $(this).css('color'),
    bg = wrap.css('backgroundColor');
  
  console.log(color + ' ' + bg);
  
  if(color === bg) {
    $this.css({'color':'#ffffff'});
  }
});
```

```css
.orig {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.invert {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div class="orig"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div class="invert"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>
```

либо так:

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  var
    $this = $(this),
    wrap = $this.closest('.invert'),
    color = $(this).css('color'),
    bg = wrap.css('backgroundColor');
  
  console.log(color + ' ' + bg);
  
  if(color === bg) {
    $this.css({'color':'#ffffff'});
  }
});
```

```css
.orig {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.invert {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div class="orig"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div class="invert">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cronfy, добавила вариант

Comment: Это решение не подходит, потому что привязывается к конкретному классу `.invert`. Черный фон, как и черный цвет текста, может задаваться любым классом или в атрибутах style. P. S. решение найдено, см. принятый ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Может с фильтром `invert`?

```css
.orig {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.invert {
  background-color: #000;
}

.invert p {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div class="orig"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div class="invert"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>
```

Comment: А черный цвет на черном фоне чего делает?

Comment: @Vadizar потерялись проценты, теперь норм.

Comment: Я думал насчет этого варианта, но иногда возникают нечитабельные сочетания.

Comment: Спасибо. Понимаете, в чем фишка. Глобально решение не сработает. Нельзя задать всем `p` в контейнере `invert`. Потому что некоторые (на самом деле большинство) уже нормально написаны белым по черному. С `invert` они станут невидимыми. В принципе, ваше решение тождественно `color: white`. Задача в том, чтобы **найти именно те** `p`, в которых текст написан черным по черному, и вот уже им прописать `invert` или `color: white` и т. п. Но при этом не трогать те, где текст написан красным по черному, например.

Comment: Понял. Тогда любое цсс-решение тут вообще не в дугу, а операции с DOM - это будет издевательством над производительностью. Думаю, вам надо таки перекручивать вашу серверную часть и выпиливать все инлайновые стили.

Comment: Понятно. Вообще, я ожидал ответы вроде "да, вот есть расширение Jquery, вызываете `$.realBackground()` и получаете реальный фон элемента". Неужели нет такого?

Answer (score 3):

Любопытно.
Можно при изменении текстовой ноды ([`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) проверять её цвет, сравнивать его с чёрным и, если слишком тёмный, делать его светлее.
При сохранении, обходить дерево ([`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)), ставить тексту принудительно цвет.

Comment: При изменении/сохранении где? Предполагается, что скрипт будет работать на публичном фронтенде, и будет запускаться по document.ready.

Comment: Вы же контролируете создание в WYSIWYG. Там и проверяйте изменения. Второй путь (при загрузке обходить DOM и менять цвет) - крайний и очень плохой способ (DOM вообще лучше не трогать лишний раз, а тут всё обходить).

Comment: Так с тем, что создано в WYSIWYG приходится работать постфактум. Оно уже есть, много страниц. Даже если я запрещу это в WYSIWYG (хотя это мне видится гораздо более сложной задачей), с уже созданными страницами нужно что-то сделать.

Comment: Уже созданные можно скормить парсеру (мне нравится [`cheerio`](https://cheerio.js.org/)), обойти дерево, поменять что нужно и сохранить. А в новых нужно не запрещать WYSIWYG, а контролировать его: меняется в нём цвет, вы перехватываете это и, если текст слишком тёмный, откатываете на белый (и выводите табличку с напоминанием что нельзя использовать тёмные цвета). Или запретить подобные цвета в WYSIWYG.

Comment: Парсер можно прикрутить, но это не решит основную задачу поиска черного текста на черном фоне.

Comment: Парсер нужен только перевода существующих страницы. Для новых - достаточно контролировать редактор.

Comment: Серьезно?......

Comment: @Other вы правда не видите, что ваш ответ не решает основной вопрос? Или чего-то не вижу я. Допустим, у нас есть парсер, и даже есть код в редакторе, который контролирует изменения. Мы нашли элемент. Как узнать, написан в этом элементе цвет черным по черному или нет?

Comment: Так проверяйте. Установите контейнерам текста нужный цвет.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите сделать быстро и просто, то сделайте на нативном CSS с помощью свойства `mix-blend-mode`:

```css
p {
  color: #fff !important;;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<h2>Оригинал</h2>
<div style="background-color: #fff;"><p>Текст</p></div>

<h2>Инверсия</h2>
<div style="background-color: #000;"><p style="color: black">Текст</p></div>

<h2>mix-blend-mode</h2>
<div style="background-color: #000;"><p>Текст</p></div>
```

Comment: Не уверен, что понял, как это работает, потому что для моего случая у меня не получилось сделать рабочий вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/1qqc8v5z/1/ Нужно, чтобы в `div.invert > p` текст был виден. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: @cronfy ваша ошибка в том, что вы через style указали стили цвета для p. Никогда так не делайте.

Comment: Это не я, честное слово.

Comment: @cronfy добавил пример.

Comment: спасибо, но вы убрали стиль из `p`, а задача как раз в том, чтобы 1) либо добиться результата не делая этого 2) либо найти все `p`, в которых нужно убрать style по критериям, описанным в вопросе.

Comment: Если в `p` прописать `style='color: black'` - будет интересно :)

Comment: @cronfy а зачем вам 'style' в 'p' ? Вы не можете в админки этого явно не указывать?

Comment: Потому что есть большое количество страниц, в которых `style` прописан в `p`. Они уже существуют, и я ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Comment: @Если вам так необходимо оставлять style в p, то в чем проблема добавить  !important; к color: #fff; ??

Comment: Потому что в `style` может быть прописано не `color: #000`, а `color: red`, а также вокруг `p` может быть `div` с `background-color: white`

Comment: @cronfy в общем понятно. Я дал вам рабочее решение. Вы сейчас продолжаете выдумывать требования. Нужно изначально нормальные админки реализовывать, а не прописывать стили прямо в теги. Страниц много... А про SQL не слышали?

Comment: Слышал. Я хочу найти решение, которое позволит мне решить проблему, не изменяя код страниц. Если это невозможно, тогда да,  буду применять другие варианты, они понятны. Наверное, я вообще зря написал про админку и редактор. Извините.

Comment: @Vadizar инлайн стили могут быть результатом работы фреймворка в кишки которого лезть нельзя, какого-нибудь сборщика или еще чего-нибудь, так что да, поставить !important и сделать стиль в цсс топикстартеру может быть совершенно нерабочим решением